# What does “requested assets” mean in CloudKit and why do they quickly go out of limits?

Tags: ios, optimization, assets, cloudkit

In my small application, I use CloudKit as a database to store the content that users access.

But in the telemetry section, I see that the Assets Requested figure for the last month is close to the border of free use (1.79 GB). Despite the fact that I have only 2-3 active users now, who have downloaded a total of 49 megabytes of assets.

Can you explain to me the difference and dependence between the indicators: Assets Requested and Assets Dowloaded?

Apple documentation traditionally does not describe such nuances, and since they have also hidden information about prices for CloudKit now, I am afraid that after the promotion of the company of my application, unpleasant surprises await me

[image]